# Undefined : value.push(new Resource(item)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a factory but I'm getting a weird error.  I looked around but haven't been able to find a similar problem.  Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'value.push(new Resource(item))')`

Using angluarjs `v1.3.20`

***factory.js***

```
'use strict';

//Business service used for communicating with the articles REST endpoints
angular.module('businesses').factory('Business', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/businesses/:businessId', {
            businessId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

***test.js***

```
describe('My Service', function () {


    // Then we can start by loading the main application module
    beforeEach(module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName));

    afterEach(inject(function($httpBackend){
        //These two calls will make sure that at the end of the test, all expected http calls were made
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    }));

    it('mock http call', inject(function($httpBackend, Business) {
        var resource = new Business({
            _id:'abcd'
        });
        var arraya = [{
            _id:'abcd'
        }, {
            _id:'abcde'
        }];
        //Create an expectation for the correct url, and respond with a mock object
        $httpBackend.expectGET('api/businesses/abcd').respond(200, arraya)

        resource.$query();

        //Because we're mocking an async action, ngMock provides a method for us to explicitly flush the request
        $httpBackend.flush();

        //Now the resource should behave as expected
        console.log(resource);
        //expect(resource.name).toBe('test');
    }));

});
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: It might be stupid, but shouldn't you put the `expectGET` AFTER the `flush()` ?

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you only expect after you flushed?

```
resource.$query();

//Because we're mocking an async action, ngMock provides a method for us to explicitly flush the request
$httpBackend.flush();

//Create an expectation for the correct url, and respond with a mock object
$httpBackend.expectGET('api/businesses/abcd').respond(200, arraya);
```

Comment: Nope.  When I change the order I get `Error: Unexpected request: GET api/businesses/abcd`

Comment: Well.. I told you, It might be stupid :P Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Thanks for he effort.  Gonna update angular & see if that does the trick.